# Why custom fields are used in Braintree?

Tags: payment-gateway, braintree

Hi i am new to the **Braintree**, I am at learning stage I want to know about why custom fields are used in Braintree. in the following [tutorial](https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/dotnet/general/custom_fields) there is description about **how** custom fields are Implemented.

But I want to know **why custom fields** are used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Custom fields used to send custom data to the gateway. Nothing more. Its like key value pair.

If you think Braintree is missing any field that you want to add you can do that with custom fields. If you send a custom data like `foo` as key and `bar` as value, you can get back this data from API response if its set as [**Pass Thru Field**](https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/php/general/custom_fields#pass_thru_field) or let it store in the gateway if its set as [**Stored and Pass Thru Field**](https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/php/general/custom_fields#stored_and_pass_thru_field).

Comment: @Jatt.net There are couple of [examples](https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/dotnet/transactions/custom_fields) already there.